# Little endian outcome

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, endianness

Okay, with this code I'm trying to get an output of 
*0xbf
0xa3
0x61
0xf2*
However I am getting this, 
*ffffffbf
ffffffa3
61
fffffff2*

Why are there so many f's with the ones that have a letter include in the outcome? I also have to make this show in the form of big endian, so how do I "shift" the places of the outcome?

Thanks!

```
 void extract_little(char *str,int offs, int n){ 
     int i;


     for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
         printf(" %.2x\n\n", str[i]);
         }
      }

 int main()
 {
     int i = 0xf261a3bf;
     int ofset = 1; // This isn't actually doing anything yet

     extract_little((char *)&i, ofset, sizeof(i));
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Reverse print order : `for (i = n; i > 0; ){ printf("%02hhx ", str[--i]); }`.  Use `hhx` is you have a C99+ compiler or `"%02x"` and (unsigned char) as @Chris suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Your platform uses signed `char`s, which gets promoted to `int` with sign extension when you call `printf`. To fix this, in your `printf` line, use `(unsigned char) str[i]`, thus:

```
printf(" %.2x\n\n", (unsigned char) str[i]);
```

Comment: Wow fantastic! Thank you! Now, if I wanted to switch these numbers around to big endian, is it possible?

Comment: reverse the for loop and the result will be reversed. anyway, use a built-in function to convert endian is much faster